# Django distincted queryset slicing does not have consistency

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I have queryset of empoyees-attendance and i am doing aggregation & disctinction on (current day, employee code). I got  distincted queryset, Afterthat i am doing slicing, and found slicing consistency not happenning as we are expecting. I am adding screenshot of reference here. Could you please anyone explain this behaviour and how we can overcome this?

[image]

[image: Queryset construction]

Comment: Have you ordered your resultset ?  
Could you share your queryset construction ?

Comment: please add your code and query to question for better response.

Comment: @Alombaros I added my queryset construction as screenshot. please take a look